# Application.Clean on Variant/String type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that worked previously but no longer does. I had assumed I messed up another section but after hours of debugging I have found some very odd results. Hopefully I simply mangled the code and it's a simple fix.

The original code that no longer works:

```
Private Function CleanColumn(ByRef Column As Range)
    Dim MyCells() As Variant
    MyCells = Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value
    MyCells = Application.Clean(MyCells)
    Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value = MyCells
End Function
```

It is simply returning an error 13, type mismatch. This is against 47k records, so it was near impossible for me to go through one by one to find the problem, so I rewrote to the following to help diagnose:

```
Private Function CleanColumn(ByRef Column As Range)
    Dim MyCells() As Variant
    MyCells = Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value

    Dim MyCell As Variant
    For Each MyCell In MyCells
        If VarType(MyCell) = vbString And Not IsNull(MyCell) And Not Left(MyCell, 4) = "=HYPE" Then
            MyCell = Application.Clean(MyCell)
        Else
            MsgBox 911
        End If
    Next
    Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value = MyCells
End Function
```

`MsgBox 911` never executes, nor does a breakpoint placed on the line hit. The code works as expected.

Figuring I was crazy, I added `MyCells = Application.Clean(MyCells)` back in like so:

```
Private Function CleanColumn(ByRef Column As Range)
    Dim MyCells() As Variant
    MyCells = Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value

    Dim MyCell As Variant
    For Each MyCell In MyCells
        If VarType(MyCell) = vbString And Not IsNull(MyCell) And Not Left(MyCell, 4) = "=HYPE" Then
            MyCell = Application.Clean(MyCell)
        Else
            MsgBox 911
        End If
    Next
    MyCells = Application.Clean(MyCells)
    Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Value = MyCells
End Function
```

Breakpoint on `MsgBox 911` still does not hit and no exception through the loop, but still an exception on `Application.Clean(MyCells)`.

Please tell me I just missed something obvious?

Comment: Do you have to include xlErrors and xlLogical in your xlCellTypeConstants mask? Inn any event, that should be a Sub, not a Function.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. I'm really not that great at VBA, just trying to get something done on request and I'm the only one with even basic VB knowledge, which makes me the "VB Guy".

Comment: Note: Your code is only looking at the first `Area` in `Column` - i.e. if the address of your `Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)` was `$A$1:$A$2,$A$4,$A$6:$A$9,$A$12`, then you are only looking at the `$A$1:$A$2` part.  (I can't see how that will cause your problem though, because you are **consistently** only looking at that first part.)

Comment: The first part of my previous comment should have been "Your code is only looking at the first `Area` in `Column.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)`".  And, actually, the fact that you are only using one area will cause issues when you go to write the values back - in my example the 2 values cleaned from `$A$1:$A$2` will be written to `$A$1:$A$2`, and `$A$1` will be written to `$A$4`, and `$A$1:$A$2` will be written to `$A$6:$A$7` with `#N/A` being placed in `$A$8:$A$9`, and `$A$1` will be written to `$A$12`.